# Right way to backup database in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I know a simple way that can back up database. Its directly have a copy of the .db file. But the issue is when you have to update the database tables with new columns, then the backups are of no use as it is with the old design.

The work around is to have the data parsed and stored into a file. But I am not sure how easy and safe is this.

Please let me know what you feel about this subject and also let me know if you have a better idea is mind. A sample code would be handy. Thank you for your advice and time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bring an interesting point up - I haven't personally thought of that before.

You can always store the "version" of your database in the database file itself (perhaps in the file name). Then, when you open the database, you can retrieve its version and have the `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` run its `onUpgrade()` method to add any new columns.

Comment: But In this case, if you have a database that is backed up with old data with version 1. And you have version 2 installed. Now if you wish to update the data alone from old back up and also retain the new columns created, How do you do this?

Comment: your onUpgrade doesnt have to necessarily have to "drop if exists" and onCreate again... you could have specific methods set aside (one per DB upgrade) that add your rows / columns necessary. If you wish to have specific values in each of those new column slots you will have to iterate through your table.